# Why different available updates in Drush to admin/reports/updates?

Tags: 7, drush, updating, log-messages

e.g. in the GUI, I'm told (after running admin/reports/updates/update) that I can update 10 modules. But `drush rf; drush up` tells me that only three updates are available. Specific example: the GUI says I can update to Views 7.x-3.3, but `drush up views` says "no code updates available."

I usually **prefer to use drush** to do the updates since I don't want to [pass credentials to my server's user account](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/how-to-update-drupal-securely-using-gui-web-interface) over the unencrypted web!

But I don't get why drush should report update status differently? Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it was using an old (i.e. Debian Squeeze's) version of Drush. Solution:

Add backports to `sources.list`

```
#
# squeeze backports
#
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then `apt-get install drush=4.5-2~bpo60+1`

Your version number may vary. Check `apt-cache policy drush` to see what versions are available.